# python slackclient userslist

Tags: python, json, slack-api

I am trying to use python slackclient. 
I am getting json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error for this, print (slack_client.api_call("users.list")) in the below code.  I tried like this, but still getting error, print (json.loads(slack_client.api_call("users.list")))
please suggest what could be wrong, 
the first 2 api calls works fine and return result. only the users list api call is giving me error

```
print (slack_client.api_call("api.test"))
print (slack_client.api_call("auth.test"))
print (slack_client.api_call("users.list"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print_bot_id.py", line 15, in <module>
    print (slack_client.api_call("users.list"))
  File "/Users/vt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/_client.py", line 83, in api_call
    result = json.loads(self.server.api_call(method, timeout=timeout, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/vt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/vt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/vt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

@smarx ,  curl for the users.list endpoint returns nothing, is there different end point

```
    $ curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/api.test?token='abc'
{"ok":true,"args":{"token":"abc"}}
m-C02KL0B1FFT4:slack_bot vt$ curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/users.list?token='abc'
$
```

Comment: That code works fine for me (under Python 3.5). It could be a specific error with your Slack instance. Could you try making the request manually (e.g. via `curl`) to see what comes back?

Comment: Example `curl` command: `curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=<YOUR-TOKEN-HERE>`

Comment: @smarx ,  curl for the users.list endpoint returns nothing, is there different end point                                                                                        $ curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/api.test?token='abc'
{"ok":true,"args":{"token":"abc"}}
m-C02KL0B1FFT4:slack_bot vt$ curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/users.list?token='abc'
m-C02KL0B1FFT4:slack_bot vt$

Comment: Could you fix the formatting in your comment? (Use backticks.) Is nothing at all being returned from the call to `users.list`? Or did that get lost in copy/pasting somehow? (It may be easier to edit your question instead.)

Comment: yeah, nothing is returned, edited the question

Comment: Could you try `curl -v ...`? I wonder what the status code is. But you'll probably need to reach out to Slack's support team, since this issue seems specific to your Slack instance or token or something.